# MVC fail to redirect after post. Status 302 but without location header

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, http, iis

mvc project added in IIS but fail to redirect to another page after post.
Status 302 but without location header

Comment: Show us your code so we can help you.

Comment: i do the redirect like this  " return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");" after checking of the user login. it work on my pc, but after i put into server 2008r2 then cant work anymore. I use Fiddler to track the http status and found out status 302 response but the location header is missing.